# How to create a jump menu in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

Can anyone tell me how i can create a jump menu in cakephp? Just like the one we have in normal HTML!

Comment: Coz im not getting enough attention on this problem!

Comment: What do you mean with "jump menu"?

Comment: A menu with links as option values. Just like the one in html

Comment: Still not clear.. Can you describe what a jump menu looks like and how is it different from a normal menu?

Comment: One would assume an HTML dropdown with links and an onchange="window.location = document.forms.myform.myfield[selectedindex]" or similar

Answer (score 1):

If you can create it in "normal html" then do so. Cake view templates are just html and embedded php.

If you keep posting redundant, informationless questions over and over then eventually we will stop bothering to look at your posts.

Just a suggestion - since "jump menu" isn't in any HTML specs and nobody seems to know what you mean how about you enlighten us as to what the question is and what you mean when you say 'jump menu' and 'regular html'